# Social Login with protractor

Tags: angularjs, authentication, protractor

I'm trying to login in my app with google and protractor. I can't find the error. It seems that a element is not present but the element is working fine in the test. Please help me with this.

Here is the test's code

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        var popupHandle = handles[1];
        browser.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
        var email = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('Email'));
        var signIn = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('signIn'));
        email.sendKeys(browser.params.login.user || process.env.GOOGLE_USER);
        signIn.click();
        browser.driver.sleep(2000);

        var password = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('Passwd'));
        password.sendKeys(browser.params.login.password || process.env.GOOGLE_PASS);
        var login = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.rc-button'));
        login.click();
        browser.driver.sleep(10000);
        browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);

    });
```

and here is the error

```
16:30:05.655 INFO - Done: [find element: By.cssSelector: *[name="signIn"]]
16:30:05.659 INFO - Executing: [click: 3 [[ChromeDriver: chrome on LINUX (e0625e8b3f72a0f40228f4f4e90c2c9d)] -> css selector: *[name="signIn"]]])
16:30:05.945 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

I don't know if there is a workaround to do this but I can't find a solution in order to login with protractor. Please help

Answer (score 0):

May be your sign-in button is enabled only after your email is validated. You should do something like below

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(signIn,5000).then(function() { signIn.click()}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you... I've tried that but it doesn't work... What really worked for me was put the login code into the onPrepare function in the config file.

Like this.

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var site = browser.params.site;
    browser.get(site);
    element(by.css('.btn-crearseguro-nav')).click();
    element(by.id('gm')).click();
    //Sign in with to popup
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        var popupHandle = handles[1];
        browser.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
        var email = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('Email'));
        var signIn = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('signIn'));
        email.sendKeys(browser.params.login.user || process.env.GOOGLE_USER);
        signIn.click();
        browser.driver.sleep(10000);

        var password = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('Passwd'));
        password.sendKeys(browser.params.login.password || process.env.GOOGLE_PASS);
        var login = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('signIn'));
        login.click();
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);
        browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
    });
},
```

And it work's fine... But thanks for yout comment... Sure I will use it in another test (y)